# Scala and Play! framework form error

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I've implemented this form

```
val contactForm : Form[Contact] = Form(

                 mapping(
                "id" -> ignored(NotAssigned: anorm.Pk[Long]),
                "fax" -> longNumber,
                "person" ->nonEmptyText,
                "mobilePhone" -> longNumber,
                "phone" -> longNumber,
                "email" -> nonEmptyText,
                "supplierId"-> mapping(
                                    "id" -> ignored(NotAssigned: anorm.Pk[Long]),
                                    "identityId" -> mapping(
                                                "id" -> ignored(NotAssigned: anorm.Pk[Long]),
                                                "codiceFornitore" -> number,
                                                "supplierType" -> nonEmptyText,
                                                "ragioneSociale" -> nonEmptyText,
                                                "partitaIva" -> longNumber,
                                                "isProduction" -> boolean //act as boolean 0=FALSE
                                    )(SupplierIdentity.apply)(SupplierIdentity.unapply),
                                    "addressId" ->  mapping(
                                                "id" -> ignored(NotAssigned: anorm.Pk[Long]),
                                                "via" -> nonEmptyText,
                                                "cap" -> number,
                                                "comune" -> nonEmptyText,
                                                "provincia" -> nonEmptyText,
                                                "paese" -> nonEmptyText
                                    )(Address.apply)(Address.unapply),
                                    "userId" -> mapping(
                                            "id" -> ignored(NotAssigned: anorm.Pk[Long]),
                                            "name" -> nonEmptyText
                                    )(User.apply)(User.unapply))
                (Supplier.apply)(Supplier.unapply)          
            )(Contact.apply)(Contact.unapply)   
    )`
```

Where Contact, SupplierIdentity, Supplier, Address and User are Case Class.
And this is my template

```
@(supplier: Supplier, contactForm : Form[Contact])
.
.
.
@form(routes.FinanceController.addContact(supplier.id.get)) {



                @helper.input(contactForm("fax"), '_id -> "fax", '_label->"Fax" , '_error -> contactForm.error("fax")) { (id, name, value, args) => 
                <input type="text" id="@id" name="@name" value="" @toHtmlArgs(args)>
                }
                @helper.input(contactForm("person"), '_id -> "person", '_label->"Figura di Riferiment", '_error -> contactForm.error("person")) { (id, name, value, args) => 
                <input type="text" id="@id" name="@name" value="" @toHtmlArgs(args)>
                }
                @helper.input(contactForm("mobilePhone"), '_id -> "mobilePhone", '_label->"Cellulare", '_error -> contactForm.error("mobilePhone")) { (id, name, value, args) => 
                <input type="text" id="@id" name="@name" value="" @toHtmlArgs(args)>
                }
                @helper.input(contactForm("phone"), '_id -> "phone", '_label->"Cellulare", '_error -> contactForm.error("phone")) { (id, name, value, args) => 
                <input type="text" id="@id" name="@name" value="" @toHtmlArgs(args)>
                }
                @helper.input(contactForm("email"), '_id -> "email", '_label->"E-mail", '_error -> contactForm.error("email")) { (id, name, value, args) => 
                <input type="text" id="@id" name="@name" value="" @toHtmlArgs(args)>
                }
                @helper.input(contactForm("supplierId"), '_id -> "supplierId", '_error -> contactForm.error("supplierId")) { (id, name, value, args) => 
                <input type="hidden" id="@id" name="@name" value="@{supplier}" @toHtmlArgs(args)>
                }

            <input type="submit" value="Create">
             }
```

But when I try to use this I get this error :

> List(FormError(supplierId.identityId.codiceFornitore,error.required,List()),
>   FormError(supplierId.identityId.supplierType,error.required,List()),
>   FormError(supplierId.identityId.ragioneSociale,error.required,List()),
>   FormError(supplierId.identityId.partitaIva,error.required,List()),
>   FormError(supplierId.addressId.via,error.required,List()),
>   FormError(supplierId.addressId.cap,error.required,List()),
>   FormError(supplierId.addressId.comune,error.required,List()),
>   FormError(supplierId.addressId.provincia,error.required,List()),
>   FormError(supplierId.addressId.paese,error.required,List()),
>   FormError(supplierId.userId.name,error.required,List()))

I'm really stuck in this error, and I can't get where is the error, I don't have any List!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paths in your error messages indicate form elements which aren't accounted for in your form.  For example, the error `FormError(supplierId.identityId.supplierType,error.required,List())` indicates that the form in your view did not provide a value for `Contact.Supplier.SupplierIdentity.SupplierType`.

I suspect you *don't* want to include the entire `Supplier` with your `Contact`, just the ID (since you called the field `supplierId`).  I would revisit your `Form[Contact]` definition or even the definition of `Contact` itself.

Comment: I suspected this, and the problem is exactly that I would like to include all Contact class, but thanks anyway, now I know exactly what is my problem.